# SonarQube github pull request plugin deletes my comments

Tags: sonarqube

I've setup the SonarQube Github pull request plugin triggered through Jenkins. 
The plugin uses my personal account, using an oAuth token, to post comments to the pull request. This all works fine except that the plugin also deletes all comments that I posted in the pull request when the plugin runs again on the same PR. It the only solution to this to use a different (non-human) account for the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the [official documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) of the GitHub plugin, in the "Requirements" part:

> You have a dedicated technical GitHub user which will be used to
>   insert comments when there are issues and update the status of the
>   pull request.

This is the expected behaviour because this "technical" GitHub user will remove its previous comments when it detects that you have fixed some previously-detected issues when you push new commits. This is to keep the PR readable.

So indeed you can't just use your own account.